# in swift3 and xcode 8.1,introduce a new DispatchQueue,can i use it back up to ios 9.0?

Tags: ios, xcode

in xcode 8.1

```
//Move to a background thread to do some long running work
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
    let image = self.loadOrGenerateAnImage()
    // Bounce back to the main thread to update the UI
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.imageView.image = image
     }
}
```

I get some error with above code ,it suggests me to use the DispatchQueue which is available in iOS 10.0, how to clear this error and also Compatible with ios9.0. I going to use @available and #available to detemine the runtime
platform

Comment: What do you exactly want? This code in iOS 9?

Comment: Yes, you can use. May i know what error you are getting?

Comment: @DharmbirSingh . The error : 'dispatch_async' has been replaced by instance method 'DispatchQueue.asynchronously(execute:)'..... 'dispatch_get_global_queue' has been replaced by 'DispatchQueue.global(attributes:)' . .....  'DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT' has been renamed to 'DispatchQueue.GlobalQueuePriority.default'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For swift 3 you can do it like this

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    let image = self.loadOrGenerateAnImage()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.imageView.image = image
    }
}
```

Comment: can it run on ios 9,ios 8 or only run on the ios 10 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Yes you can use that in iOS 8 or 9. In iOS that it will be different. 
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
            let image = self.loadOrGenerateAnImage()
            // Bounce back to the main thread to update the UI
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.imageView.image = image
            }
        }
```